# File storing on Ruby/Rake/Grape server

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-grape, file-storage

I am trying to find out a solution for the solution I want to implement.

I would like to store "avatar"s on my server for my users.

But I would like the images to be accessible only if you have a valid session token and a valid user_id.

I would rather not store the images in the database if possible.

I am using Ruby, with Rake, ActiveRecord, and Grape. It is an API not a website.
I use mySQL as a database.

The server is an Apache using passenger to interpretate the ruby.

Do you know if it is possible to serve an image, like apache would do it when you access one but beeing able to control the access to this image using my access tokens?

Comment: What's the server technology? Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use paperclip to store your images it has option for uri obfuscation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#uri-obfuscation

I use it in combination with grape as well and it works fine for me.